# Mount configmap from GoogleCloudStorage into Google Kubernetes Engine pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In a multi-tenant environment, I'd like to put several configmap (each for customer) into GoogleCloudStorage bucket, and recall a precise configmap in the deployment yaml by using an environment variable (same name as the configmap), without using a startup script. Is it possible to do by using yaml or other ways?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a distinguishing name of the customer (e.g. namespace) available you can have that as env var in yaml via downward api. Then in your entrypoint you could construct the url.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replu, do you have some references?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api

Comment: Seems different from I'm looking for. I want to use an environment var to download configmap from storage bucket

Comment: Fair enough, although it could work if your stored your data at `${well_known_bucket}/${namespace}/configmap`.

The `well_known_bucket` could potentially be stored in custom instance metadata. Or it could be stored in an annotation and processed from a file in your pod.

There are many ways to do this, the most frequent is via a config management tool like helm.

Comment: Or maybe what you're looking for is an init container if you don't have access to the main container's Dockerfile(it can copy it into the relevant directory).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/